# How to publish two test result set with cake build system on azure devops

Tags: c#, azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines, build-system

I have one test project that run with NUnit3 Runner in cake that generate test result in test1.xml with NUnit format, and I have another test project that run with VSTest Runner in cake that generate test result in test2.xml with VSTest format.

My question is How to publish two test result into Azure DevOps with one command? or any other way exist to combine these files?

My command is like below

```
    if (testProjects.Any() && AzurePipelines.IsRunningOnAzurePipelines || AzurePipelines.IsRunningOnAzurePipelinesHosted)
    {
        Information("Publish test result.....................................");
        if (testResultsFiles.Any())
        {
            AzurePipelines.Commands.PublishTestResults(
                new AzurePipelinesPublishTestResultsData
                {
                    TestResultsFiles = testResultsFiles.ToArray(),
                    TestRunner = AzurePipelinesTestRunnerType.NUnit
                }
            );
        }
        if (vsTestResultsFiles.Any())
        {
            AzurePipelines.Commands.PublishTestResults(
                new AzurePipelinesPublishTestResultsData
                {
                    TestResultsFiles = vsTestResultsFiles.ToArray(),
                    TestRunner = AzurePipelinesTestRunnerType.VSTest
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

but As you can see above code, I write two publish method that is very bad, So I want to find a way that can send all test result in one command

[GitHub disscussion](https://github.com/cake-build/cake/discussions/3137#discussion-3221213)

Comment: Where are you performing these tests? Local or Azure Pipeline?  If you are using the azure Pipeline, have you tried to directly use the task : [Publish Test Results task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=trx%2Cyaml)

Comment: I want to use cake file instead of azure specific task, because I want to write all build pipeline code in one location.